# Xamarin Binding library error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've successfully bound the following Android library to Xamarin. But when I try to use it, the app crashes with an Unhandled Exception. Following is the output being printed.

[ChromeLikeTabSwitcher](https://github.com/michael-rapp/ChromeLikeTabSwitcher)

```
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): Process: App1.App1, PID: 8646
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:616)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6846)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7014)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:741)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:685)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:62)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.phone.PhoneTabSwitcherLayout.onInflateLayout(PhoneTabSwitcherLayout.java:3348)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.AbstractTabSwitcherLayout.inflateLayout(AbstractTabSwitcherLayout.java:489)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.TabSwitcher.initializeLayout(TabSwitcher.java:241)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.TabSwitcher.access$900(TabSwitcher.java:97)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.TabSwitcher$5.onGlobalLayout(TabSwitcher.java:657)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.AbstractTabSwitcherLayout$LayoutListenerWrapper.onGlobalLayout(AbstractTabSwitcherLayout.java:112)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:986)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7016)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
12-21 10:47:44.096 E/AndroidRuntime( 8646): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

**Missing Class Warnings**

```
Couldn't load class de/mrapp/android/tabswitcher/layout/phone/PreviewDataBinder : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/mrapp/android/util/multithreading/AbstractDataBinder
Couldn't load class de/mrapp/android/tabswitcher/layout/phone/PhoneRecyclerAdapter : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/mrapp/android/util/multithreading/AbstractDataBinder$Listener       
missing class error was raised while reflecting de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.phone.PhoneRecyclerAdapter$1 : de/mrapp/android/util/multithreading/AbstractDataBinder$Listener     
missing class error was raised while reflecting de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.phone.PhoneTabSwitcherLayout : de/mrapp/android/util/multithreading/AbstractDataBinder$Listener
```

**Util library error**

```
Error   CS1519  Invalid token 'params' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\sdheshan\source\repos\ClassLibrary3\Util\obj\Debug\generated\src\DE.Mrapp.Android.Util.Multithreading.AbstractDataBinder.cs
```

Cause of the Util library error

```
params global:: Java.Lang.Object[] p4;
        public params global:: Java.Lang.Object[] P4 {
            get { return p4; }
        }
```

Comment: The issue is, some classes from the original library are not being generated by the binding library. For example the following class does not exist. de.mrapp.android.tabswitcher.layout.phone.PhoneTabSwitcherLayout

Comment: Check the `warning` of the binding project build output to see if those classes are not been generated due to some issue...

Comment: Ok. Will check it out.

Comment: @SushiHangover I've found the warnings. Please see the edited question.

Comment: What is the default visibility of the `AbstractDataBinder` java class? As you might need a transform to make it public.

Comment: @SushiHangover after further digging I found that the util reference library fails to build and the same class is causing the issue. Error added to the question.

Comment: @SushiHangover added the code snippet which is causing the error inside the generated class.

Comment: Did you not include `android-util-1.18.2.aar` in your binding project?

Comment: I created a separate binding project for that library(android-util-1.18.2.aar) and referenced it from the tab switcher library. I think it's the right way?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1138

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover. Hope to hear from Xamarin soon. :)